# i want get token Oauth2 by postman

Tags: java, spring-boot, security, oauth-2.0, jhipster

I am trying this way to get a token, but there is some problem in accessing the client
[image]

i can Login from  Login layout i can access by username= admin and password= admin
but in the post man i cant access and the result form request is

```
    {
    "error": "unauthorized_client",
    "error_description": "Client not allowed for direct access grants"
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you should be change client_id to  direct access grants
like this image

[image]